# Generalization of representing SU(2) as quaternions

Tags: resource-request, bloch-sphere

I am familiar with the isomorphism between $SU(2)$ and the unit quaternions, and the group homomorphism from them to $SO(3)$. I am interested in knowing if there is a generalization for $SU(2^n)$. My motivation is both general interest, and technical in that working with quaternions as pairs of real numbers as opposed to matrices is easier for my application.

This led me to read about the Hopf fibration and its relationship to the Bloch sphere (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0310053)) for the cases of one through three qubits, which seemed to suggest that it might be possible at least for some dimensions using quaternions, octonions, etc. but I wasn't sure.

Comment: the isomorphism (that is not an isomorphism actually, it's a double covering) between $\mathbf{SO}(3)$ and $\mathbf{SU}(2)$ doesn't immediately generalise, if that's what you're asking. Which is the reason why only for single qubits the space of states is a sphere, while the state space in higher dimensions has a much more complex geometry. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4182160/173147 about what Hopf's fibration looks like in higher dimensions

Comment: @glS I think you misunderstood my question (though the link is interesting anyway). My question is about SU(4), SU(8), etc.: can they also be written in terms of quaternions, or maybe a higher dimensional analog like octonions?